# SQL Server 2008 while loop for search

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, while-loop

I'm trying to write a query for searching hotel rooms.

I get check in date and day of staying nights from user.

I have written a while loop for staying nights. So it adds one day to check in date in while loop. Is this the good way or you guys have any different ideas?

Thanks...
Happy coding

Comment: SQL is language that works on sets of data. In 90% of cases whatever is done in a loop can be done in 1-2 TSQL statements

Comment: @YuriyGalanter . . . More like 99%.

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) SQL databases perform much better with set operations than with while loops.  A *better* approach for your case (which is quite vague) would be to search for rooms that have availability on all dates between `{check-in date}` and `{check-in date + (nights-1)}`